# How to transfer pandas .plot() to Matplotlib .errorbar()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, errorbar

I'm looking to plot **error bars** on a line plot I did using pandas's `.plot()` function

```
scores_xgb.plot(x='size', y='MSE_mean_tot', kind='line',logx=True,title='XGBoost 5 samples, 5 fold CV')
```

Running this gives me the following plot:

[image]

For plotting the error bars, I choose to use `.errorbar()` from Matplotlib. When running the cell

```
plt.errorbar(x=scores_xgb.size, y=scores_xgb.MSE_mean_tot, yerr=std_xgb ,title='XGBoost 5 samples, 5 fold CV')
plt.show()
```

I receive the following error message:

```
ValueError: 'x' and 'y' must have the same size
```

This confuses me, as I use the same Dataframe in both examples, each time using the **same variable** for `x` and `y` respectively, therefore it has the same size (12) both times.

**NB:** the `yerr = std_xgb` also has size 12.

Comment: Do you have a `size` column in your dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I have a column `size` in this dataframe. It contains information about the number of rows of other dataframes on which my models are trained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property on `pandas.DataFrame` objects named `size`, and it's a number, equal to the number of cells in the DataFrame (the product of the values in `df.shape`). You're trying to access a *column* named `size`, but pandas chooses the property named `size` **before** it chooses the column name `size`. Since the single number has a shape of 1 but the columns in the dataframe have a length of 12, you're getting a shape mismatch.

Instead, use strings to index the dataframe and get the the columns:

```
plt.errorbar(x=scores_xgb['size'], y=scores_xgb['MSE_mean_tot'], yerr=std_xgb, title='XGBoost 5 samples, 5 fold CV')
```